# jQuery center specific table columns

Tags: jquery, html-table, center, styling

I have a host of legacy code that I need to adapt but don't have the time to fully modify.

Is it possible to have jQuery 'center' the contents of a table column if they don't have an `id`, `name` or `class`.

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Text</td><td>Col2</td><td>Col3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Text</td><td>Col2</td><td>Col3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Text</td><td>Col2</td><td>Col3</td></tr>
</table>
```

What I was wondering was if it were possible to center the contents of the 2nd and 3rd columns, parent/ child for example but I'm not sure if it is possible.

I could go and recode all the tables (which are hard coded on the .php page) but that would take hours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
  var tds = $(this).find('td');
  var len = tds.length;
  for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    $(tds[i]).css('text-align', 'center');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
var row = 1;//row number
var column = 1;//column number
$('table tr:nth-child(' + row + ') td:nth-child(' + column + ')').css('text-align', 'center');
```

Comment: This is good. But it may work slowly on big tables because of difficult selector.

Comment: Thanks roullie - appreciate you taking the time to respond but I have accepted Sanja's solution.